# XGBoost feature importance (TFIDF + TruncateSVD)

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

I have an XGBoost model that runs TFIDF vectorization and TruncateSVD reduction on text features. I want to understand feature importance of the model.

This is how I process text features in my dataset:

```
    .......
    tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize)
    tfs = tfidf.fit_transform(token_dict)
    
    svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=15)
    temp = pd.DataFrame(svd.fit_transform(tfs))
    temp.rename(columns=lambda x: text_feature+'_'+str(x), inplace=True)

    dataset=dataset.join(temp,how='inner')
    .......
```

It works okayish and now I'm trying to understand importance of the features in the dataset. I generate the charts using:

```
xgb.plot_importance(model, max_num_features=15)
pyplot.show()
```

And get something similar to:
[this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAoj7.png)

What would be the right way to "map" importance SVD dimensions to the dimensions of the initial dataset? So I know importance of `summary` and not `summary_1`, `summary_2`, `summary_X`.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

one thing you can try is getting the how important each original feature is to creating new features. you can get it using the following:

```
feature_importance_scores = np.abs(svd.components_).sum(axis=0)
feature_importance_scores /= feature_importance_scores.sum() # normalize to make it more clear
```

you can get the overall importance by multiplying these values with `xgb.feature_importances_`